# Display dynamic columns data with next and prev buttons in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, html-table, jstl

I'm displaying my table values using arraylists with jstl tags on jsp pages.
Here's the code:

```
<table class="box-table" summary="Shift details">
            <!-- column headers -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <c:forEach var="columnName" items="${columnHeader}">
                        <th scope="col"><c:out value="${columnName}" /></th>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- column data -->
            <tbody>

                <c:forEach var="row" varStatus="altrow" items="${tableData}">
                    <tr class="${altrow.index % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                        <c:forEach var="column" items="${row}">
                            <td><c:out value="${column}" /></td>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the code, columnHeader is arraylist for column data and tableData is arraylist for rows data. Everything is good till now.. but rows are static (each row indicates a user's data for that date) and column data(dates) is dynamic. So I want to display something like this..

[image: Displays data for 10 only]

Suppose I have an arraylist of 30 dates but I need to display only 10 dates and remaining 10 on click of next button and so on, navigate back when prev button pressed.

Please point me in the right direction to achieve this...

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that with palin`jstl` . But there are several `jquery` plugins , you can implement pagination using them .

And one among them is [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: thank you for the plugin, i'm doing some research about this and let u know the results!